# Stash get_list and prefix: variables not rendering

Tags: stash

Using EE 273 and stash 252.

As soon as I add a prefix parameter to a `get_list`, stash variables inside the list are not rendering.

**Set_list part**

```
{!-- Get last 3 news --}
{exp:stash:set_list name="st_latestnews" parse_tags="yes"}

    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="news"
        disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
        orderby="date"
        sort="desc"
        limit="3"
        dynamic="no"
    }
        {stash:st_item_title}{title}{/stash:st_item_title}
        {stash:st_item_url}{url_title_path="news_press/news_detail"}{/stash:st_item_url}
        {stash:st_item_date}{entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"}{/stash:st_item_date}
        {stash:st_item_machinedate}{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d"}{/stash:st_item_machinedate}
        {stash:st_item_img}{news_img}{/stash:st_item_img}
        {stash:st_item_img_caption}{news_img_caption}{/stash:st_item_img_caption}
        {stash:st_item_img_copyright}{news_img_copyright}{/stash:st_item_img_copyright}
        {stash:st_item_summary}{news_summary}{/stash:st_item_summary}
    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

**Get list without prefix: works (but no_results does not)**

Everything is rendered fine but no_results does not work here. Tried adding `parse_conditionals="yes"` and `parse_tags="yes"` but no dice.

```
{!-- display news list --}
{exp:stash:get_list name="st_latestnews"}

    {if count == 1}<ul class="list-compact  grid"><li class="grid__unit  medium-unit-4of12">{/if}
        <article>
            <p class="imgholder"><a href="{st_item_url}">{exp:ce_img:pair src="{st_item_img}" width="600" height="337" crop="yes|center,center" allow_scale_larger="yes"}<img src="{made}" alt="{st_item_img_caption} - &copy; {st_item_img_copyright}" class="fluidimg" />{/exp:ce_img:pair}</a></p>
            <p class="item-meta"><time datetime="{st_item_mdate}">{st_item_date}</time></p>
            <h2 class="item-title  item-title--small"><a href="{st_item_url}">{st_item_title}</a></h2>
            <p>{exp:eehive_hacksaw words="30" append="&hellip;"}{st_item_summary}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}</p>
        </article>
    {if count == total_results}</li></ul>{if:else}</li><li class="grid__unit  medium-unit-4of12">{/if}

    {!-- handling no result --}
    {if no_results}<p>No news found</p>{/if}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

**Get list with prefix: variables do not render (but no_results works)**

With previous versions of Stash, this used to work to get the no_results tag to behave properly. Here, as soon as I add a prefix parameter, nothing renders, although the list is correctly populated and retrieved in the template debugger.

```
{!-- display news list --}
{exp:stash:get_list name="st_latestnews" prefix="stashprefix"}

    {if count == 1}<ul class="list-compact  grid"><li class="grid__unit  medium-unit-4of12">{/if}
        <article>
            <p class="imgholder"><a href="{st_item_url}">{exp:ce_img:pair src="{st_item_img}" width="600" height="337" crop="yes|center,center" allow_scale_larger="yes"}<img src="{made}" alt="{st_item_img_caption} - &copy; {st_item_img_copyright}" class="fluidimg" />{/exp:ce_img:pair}</a></p>
            <p class="item-meta"><time datetime="{st_item_mdate}">{st_item_date}</time></p>
            <h2 class="item-title  item-title--small"><a href="{st_item_url}">{st_item_title}</a></h2>
            <p>{exp:eehive_hacksaw words="30" append="&hellip;"}{st_item_summary}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}</p>
        </article>
    {if count == total_results}</li></ul>{if:else}</li><li class="grid__unit  medium-unit-4of12">{/if}

    {!-- handling no result --}
    {if stashprefix:no_results}<p>No news found</p>{/if}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious here (as it could well be the case) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ever helpful Mark Croxton [promptly responded via twitter](https://twitter.com/croxton/status/453462539251486720).

From the changelog:

> Stash 2.4.8: When using the `prefix="x"`, parameter with `get_list`,
>   only prefixed variables will now be parsed by default, unless
>   `require_prefix="no"`

So the correct code for your variables to be parsed without prefix and the no_result tag to be working is as follows:

```
{!-- display news list --}
{exp:stash:get_list name="st_latestnews" prefix="myprefix" require_prefix="no"}

    {if count == 1}<ul class="list-compact  grid"><li class="grid__unit  medium-unit-4of12">{/if}
        <article>
            <p class="imgholder"><a href="{st_item_url}">{exp:ce_img:pair src="{st_item_img}" width="600" height="337" crop="yes|center,center" allow_scale_larger="yes"}<img src="{made}" alt="{st_item_img_caption} - &copy; {st_item_img_copyright}" class="fluidimg" />{/exp:ce_img:pair}</a></p>
            <p class="item-meta"><time datetime="{st_item_mdate}">{st_item_date}</time></p>
            <h2 class="item-title  item-title--small"><a href="{st_item_url}">{st_item_title}</a></h2>
            <p>{exp:eehive_hacksaw words="30" append="&hellip;"}{st_item_summary}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}</p>
        </article>
    {if count == total_results}</li></ul>{if:else}</li><li class="grid__unit  medium-unit-4of12">{/if}

    {!-- handling no result --}
    {if myprefix:no_results}<p>No news found</p>{/if}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```